# How can I get access to this cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubeflow, istio-gateway, juju

Hello I was created a k8s cluster in vagrant using the followings commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.21/stable
sudo usermod -a -G microk8s $USER
newgrp microk8s
sudo chown -f -R $USER ~/.kube
microk8s enable dns storage ingress metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49
microk8s config > ~/.kube/config
sudo snap install juju --classic
juju bootstrap microk8s mycontroler
juju add-model kubeflow
juju deploy kubeflow-lite --trust
microk8s kubectl patch role -n kubeflow istio-ingressgateway-operator -p '{"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"name":"istio-ingressgateway-operator"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":["*"],"resources":["*"],"verbs":["*"]}]}'
juju config dex-auth public-url=http://10.64.140.43.nip.io
juju config oidc-gatekeeper public-url=http://10.64.140.43.nip.io
juju config dex-auth static-username=admin
juju config dex-auth static-password=admin
```

I copied the .kube/config from vagrant to the host and set the socks proxy to the vagrant like this

ssh -D 9999 vagrant@10.64.140.43

I cannot get access to the http://10.64.140.43.nip.io because I get a error 403 too.

any idea about how can I use kubectl from host to get access to that k8s cluster?

Thanks

Comment: you are trying to achieve `bridged networking in microk8s` , check out https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-multus OR anything on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. This is a security control that doesn't allow outside access to Vagrant networking. You need to configure port forwarding inside your vagrant `Vagrantfile` and then run `vagrant reload` for this to take effect.

You can find more details in [this stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/questions/570261/cant-ping-to-vagrant-box).